# soffice.bin X11 error: Can't open display how to resolve?

Tags: java, openoffice.org

I am developing web application using Java + OpenOffice to generate report documents.

A tomcat server and the war file is installed on a Fedora machine.

Below code works fine to create writer documents on Windows OS but giving error on the Fedora machine while calling from client side using war file:

```
String oooExeFolder = "/usr/lib/openoffice.org3/program";              
XComponentContext xContext = BootstrapSocketConnector.bootstrap(oooExeFolder);

XMultiComponentFactory xMultiComponentFactory = xContext.getServiceManager();

XComponentLoader xcomponentloader = (XComponentLoader) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XComponentLoader.class, xMultiComponentFactory.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", xContext));

XComponent xcomp = xcomponentloader.loadComponentFromURL(filep[i], "_blank", 0, new PropertyValue[0]);
```

This is the Error :

```
CE> /usr/lib/openoffice.org3/program/soffice.bin X11 error: Can't open display: 
CE>    Set DISPLAY environment variable, use -display option
CE>    or check permissions of your X-Server
CE>    (See "man X" resp. "man xhost" for details)
```

Can anyone help to identify possible causes for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
After Setting display to "1.0" with following code manually problem has been resolved and  i am able to access Open Office from web application to generate report

oooExeFolder = "/usr/lib/openoffice.org3/program/";
List<String> oooOptions = OOoServer.getDefaultOOoOptions();
oooOptions.add("-display");
oooOptions.add(":1.0");

OOoServer server = new OOoServer(oooExeFolder, oooOptions);
XComponentContext xContext = BootstrapSocketConnector.bootstrap(oooExeFolder);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to launch `soffice` in "headless" mode.  I suggest you look at [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) or [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) since they will save you a lot of time in this type of setup problem.  Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.